# Is it possible to use a custom equality operator with Ruby's Set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, set

I need to diff collections of child objects between 2 parents. Each is about 30,000 objects, and have about a dozen various attributes. Ruby's Set class provides a fast method to subtract one collection from the other, and get the difference. I had been doing this with JSON data, and the whole thing only took a couple seconds.

Now I'm using ActiveRecord to get the datasets. Of course, once the children are unmarshalled from the database, they include attributes `:id`, `:created_at`, and `:updated_at`. Unfortunately, this automatically ruins the comparisons in the diff, because these fields will always be different, and cause the comparison to fail.

Out of the set of attributes, I really only care about `:label` and `:data`. That is, I want to compare the objects with the same label between the 2 sets, and see if their data is different.

I can add a custom equivalency operator in my class:

```
def ==(other)
    self.label == other.label && self.data == other.data
end
```

This works between comparisons of single objects. They are considered equal if (just) their labels and data match. However, this override does not seem to be getting used in this operation, for purposes of determining equivalency:

```
@diff = (@left.to_set - @right.to_set)
```

I was hoping that Set would use the object's class' overridden == operator, but this doesn't seem to be the case.  My diffs are just all of the one side or the other, depending on the order of the difference. Is there any way to make this happen? (I already also tried overriding `.eql?`.)

---

Since this is too long for a comment, here's the SQL implementation of the idea.

```
WITH 
    t1 AS (SELECT * FROM tunings WHERE calibration_id = 7960),
    t2 AS (SELECT * FROM tunings WHERE calibration_id = 7965)
SELECT t1.label, t1."data", t2."data" FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.label = t2.label
WHERE t1."data" != t2."data" OR t1."data" IS NULL OR t2."data" IS NULL
```

Another speed problem I hadn't even brought up yet was that I have to LOOK UP the "right" value, from the corresponding set, when I display the differences in the view, and THAT takes ANOTHER 10 seconds. This is all done in one step.

Because of the CTE's, I'm guessing that I won't be able to put this into ActiveRecord semantics, and I'll just have to pass the raw SQL with seeded values, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Also, I'm still academically interested in original question.

Comment: How is the data stored in the database? DBMs have all sorts of wonderful features to do this sort of thing, and they run MUCH faster than retrieving the data and doing it in the code. It looks like it's not stored in a way that makes it easy to allow the DBM to do that though. I'd recommend looking into a better way to store the data.

Comment: Well, crap. I've spent all day digging into this, and that hadn't even crossed my mind. In usual Rails practice, all the children of the parents is in one table, identified by a parent_id field. I just tried a FULL OUTER JOIN, and 1) there are discrepancies between this and the "set" approach, so it needs more work, 2) BUT it only takes 1.5 seconds, and 3) I'm going to have to figure out how to make AR do this query. One positive is that, by doing this, I realized I hadn't yet created indexes on my label or parent_id fields, and doing that sped up both approaches considerably.

Comment: Why not just JSON dump out side A, same for side B, and string compare, or if that's impractical, SHA2-256 hash both sides and compare?

Comment: David, a reminder that when you reply to a comment you should include the target's user name (@theTinMan) so they will be notified by SO of the comment. Here TinMan would have been notified, but only because it was the only comment that preceded yours.

Comment: @tadman, while that'd work I can easily imagine situations in a busy production server where even dumping JSON and comparing as strings could be costly because of moving data back and forth. If the DBM was treating the data as strings and doing the compare then it'd be MUCH faster until the code needed to know what exactly had changed, then it'd slow way down again and cost even more than if the data was stored more granularly. The last team I worked with was doing the same thing, storing serialized objects then moving them back and forth to compare. I explained why not but they didn't care.

Comment: @theTinMan It's not always a valid approach, but for a prototype or early production stage solution it can work. For higher intensity workloads I often store a hash of large blocks of content, like JSON, to do quick comparisons on those instead. Tests for "does this exist in the database" are super fast that way, even on large lists of possible merges.

Comment: @tadman My "data" fields are JSON-encoded arrays of strings. Some of them are thousands of elements long. So, comparing the strings would have been cumbersome, and generating hashes for both sides of a 30,000-item collection seems like it would be prohibitive. Whatever the Set module is doing behind the scenes, it's impressive.

Comment: Ruby's `Set` leans heavily on `hash` and `eql?` to allow it to quickly compare equivalent values and enforce uniqueness. The `hash` method should produce identical values if the objects *could* be equivalent, there's always room for a small number of collisions, and `eql?` if they *are* equivalent. The `hash` method weeds out how many comparisons it has to do, like only those where `hash` is the same.

Comment: @tadman I was referring to your previous suggestion of generating SHA2-256 hashes. Or are you saying that's what Ruby is doing behind the scenes when it computes its hashes?

Comment: Just explaining what Ruby does internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Ruby Set class: equality of sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832703/ruby-set-class-equality-of-sets), you need to override both `Object#eql?` and `Object#hash`

Comment: This works, and makes the straight set comparison approach take just 2.5 seconds. (That's an order of magnitude better than any algorithmic approach I could come up with.) It looks like I do NOT need to ALSO override `==`. I took that override out, and the time stayed the same.

Comment: In case anyone wants to compare times for the set-based approach versus pure SQL: I tried to use Arel to do the raw query until I finally noticed that it's "outer join" was really only a "LEFT outer join." So I finally just generated the SQL as above (with substituted parameters in the right places), and now the whole thing renders in just 1.6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in general Ruby, without having to redefine your classes' identity.

```
first = [{ id: 1, label: "foo", data: "foo"},
         { id: 2, label: "bar", data: "bar"},
         { id: 3, label: "baz", data: "baz"}]
second = [{ id: 1, label: "foo", data: "foo"},
          { id: 2, label: "baz", data: "baz"},
          { id: 3, label: "quux", data: "quux"}]

first_groups = first.group_by { |e| e.values_at(:label, :data) }
second_groups = second.group_by { |e| e.values_at(:label, :data) }

first_minus_second_keys = first_groups.keys.to_set - second_groups.keys.to_set
first_minus_second = first_minus_second_keys.flat_map { |k| first_groups[k] }
```

(This is for lists of hashes; for AR classes you'd replace `e.values(:label, :data)` with `[e.label, e.data]`)

That said, I agree with the Tin Man: it would be way more performant to do this at the database level.

Comment: A pure code solution is still intriguing to me, but this example highlights a lot of problems I had in trying to code around NOT finding an answer to the original question. `.values_at()` doesn't exist for an ActiveRecord object, so I have to use `e.attributes.values_at()` and then I can't figure out what to use in place of `:label` to make it work. Debugging what I've got in the block at that point is difficult.

Comment: "(This is for lists of hashes; for AR classes you'd replace `e.values(:label, :data)` with `[e.label, e.data]`)" (except I typoed `values` for `values_at`). This calls the appropriate methods, instead of going under the hood. You could also `[:label, :data].map { |m| e.send(m) }`, which should be equivalent.

Comment: No, I caught the typo, but it was clear what you meant. I tried `e.label` and `e["label"]` (since it's a hash, at that point), but both of these resulted in `[nil, nil]` as a key, and that's where I gave up. Invoking another method on the data to transform it is only going to increase the performance penalty over the set-based approach.